# HTML Entity for DASH

Tags: html, entity

Putting two dashes on a page sometimes, like this -- in rare occassions messes the HTML up.

For instance, if you enter -- into your Wordpress blog it'll actually munch it into a single -.  This doesn't work well for code that requires --options --to --be --specified --this --way.

The HTML entity for – is &ndash and the longer — is &mdash; but what is the HTML entity to enter NORMAL DASH - in a page?

Comment: why do you need an HTML entity for normal dash?

Comment: like, r/&[nm]dash;/--/g should work right?

Comment: Because Wordpress munches up the double dash.. -- turns it into a single dash, remarkably

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do it.  It's not listed as a dash, you need to find a place that lists it as the minus sign.

Code block shows code:

```
&#45;
```

In use: -  (&#45;)
Double: --  (&#45;&#45;)

EDIT: [My source for this answer.](http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 11):

The HTML character names `dash;` and `hyphen;` (use with leading `&`) have the same Unicode, U+2010.

From Wikipedia ([Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), [Hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), [Plus and minus signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs)) and [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html):

|  | character | Unicode (hexadecimal) | HTML entity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hyphen | ‐ | U+2010 `&#x2010;` ‐ | `&dash;` ‐ `&hyphen;` ‐ |
| Figure dash | ‒ | U+2012 `&#x2012;` ‒ |  |
| En dash | – | U+2013 `&#x2013;` – | `&ndash;` – |
| Em dash | — | U+2014 `&#x2014;` — | `&mdash;` — |
| Horizontal bar | ― | U+2015 `&#x2015;` ― | `&horbar;` ― |
| minus sign | − | U+2212 `&#x2212;` − | `&minus;` − |

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Unicode also lists the unicode codes for similar characters/marks like hyphen, minus and tilde.

Also see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML

Comment: Although `&dash;` looks a lot like `-`, it actually is a completely different character to a code editor

Answer (score 7):

This tool makes it easy to find (instead of looking through a chart): http://amp-what.com/#q=dash

Answer (score 2):

Besides the "ndash" and "mdash" that you've mentioned (and which I think are valid for most uses), there is the hyphen as represented by `&hyphen;` (rendered: ‐) and the math symbol for minus represented by `&minus;` (rendered: −).

Comment: Unfortunately when copy pasted into an editor like Xcode, these _do not_ sub in for the "dash" - on your keyboard (so 3 − 7 (using &minus;) is an error in Xcode (while 3 - 7 is fine))

Comment: @bobobobo That makes sense, because they're different characters;  the subtraction operator in most programming languages is not −, but the hypen.  Similarly, * is used in place of &times;.  A programming language like [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)), on the other hand, does use actual mathematical symbols.

Comment: Well you can `#define − -`, but that will only work if you use whitespace on either side of `−`.  E.g. `3 − 7` will work, `3−7` will not.

Comment: I love the readability of this answer vs `&#45;`, but unfortunately (on GitHub Markdown, at least), they are all different sizes -- from narrowest to widest, `&hyphen;`, `&#45;`, and `&minus;`. `&#45;` looks closest to a drop-in replacement for `-` from the keyboard.